# Virtual Host points to wrong directory after changing it on Ubuntu with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2

I created a virtual host for a domain `abc.com` to point to the directory `/var/www/abc`.

So in my sites-enabled I had this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName abc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/abc
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com [OR]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

But now I wanted to change it to another directory xyz. So I ran a2dissite en created a new virtulhost which now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName abc.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/xyz
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com [OR]
        RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    </VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted apache. But when I access abc.com it still opens the website in /var/www/abc.

I cleared browser cache and cookies...

Is there any other place where I have to make changes?

Comment: Have you reloaded apache after changing the configuration files? Both VirtualHosts only apply to http/80 traffic but both redirect to https/443, have you changed the VirtualHost configuration for https/443?

Comment: Check which site is enabled (`ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`) and check what your default `DocumentRoot` points to.